# How can I add notification for changing users?

Tags: list, workflow, notifications

I have a list that contains authorities, authorized person, and delegatee. Authorized person can delegate his/her authority to anyone. I want to add a notification that is when he/she delegates, he and the delegatee receive email notification. There are more than 15 authorized persons, so how can I do this whithout using sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the alerts, but out-of-the-box, any user subscribed to alerts will get notified of any changes done on any item.

You could try something like [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/10798/51055) in item added and item updated event receivers. However that would be an overkill.

Or, you could send an email directly from ItemUpdated event receiver using [`SPUtility.SendEmail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx).